# How to set Rounded Corners of Image View?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, imageview

How to set rounded corners of `ImageView` **instead** inner Image.

I'm trying to set rounded corners of `ImageView` with glide but glide only set rounded corners of image not `ImageView`.

I create `ImageView` in `CardView`. I used pinch to zoom gesture in `ImageView`.
when i using glide to set rounded corners of `ImageView` then glide set corners of image instead `ImageView` as same as `CardView` shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview it provides lots of shapes and could help you!

At first add this dependency in you build.gradle (app)

```
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
```

Now for getting rounded corners imageview you need to use

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:siShape="@drawable/shape_rounded_rectangle"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siSquare="true"/>
```

And create a new drawable file called `shape_rounded_rectangle` containing:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="18dp"
        android:topRightRadius="18dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="18dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="18dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

To get the rectangle with borders just use

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siRadius="6dp"
    app:siBorderWidth="6dp"
    app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"
    app:siSquare="true"/>
```

And here is what you get:

[Image without borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFDtH.png)

And [Image with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hOs1.png)

Comment: thanks for answer me... but i'm using pinch to zoom gesture in image view.

Comment: I update my question. now u can try to answer

Comment: @AkashAttal try to set the cardview corners rounded instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can override onDraw method in your custom ImageView and draw RoundRect on canvas:

```java
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```